# Cannot load image from CipherInputStream

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, android-glide

Glide Version: 4.8.0

Integration libraries: None

Device/Android Version: OnePlus 3, Android 9.0

Issue details / Repro steps / Use case background: I am using Glide to load encrypted images from the local storage. I have encrypted the images using AES-128. My first approach was decoding the image and using the resulting ByteArray to load the image using Glide. This worked well for small images but gave me an OOM error for large images and when I am trying to load video thumbnails. Obviously this approach was a very naive one. I then created a custom ModelLoader to load the image using the stream but they are not loading. Seems like the problem is the decoding path.
I am new to Glide and some help would be very appriciated.

```
//one line loader
 GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(CipherInputStream(FileInputStream(File(mPaths.get(p1).mPath)), decCypher))
                .thumbnail(0.05f)
                .override(size,size)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).dontTransform())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(p0.imageView)


//custom ModelLoad
class EncryptedModelLoader : ModelLoader<CipherInputStream, CipherInputStream> {
    override fun buildLoadData(model: CipherInputStream, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Options): ModelLoader.LoadData<CipherInputStream>? {
        return ModelLoader.LoadData(ObjectKey(model.toString()), EncryptedDataFetcher(model))
    }

    override fun handles(p0: CipherInputStream): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}

//custom DataFetcher
class EncryptedDataFetcher : DataFetcher<CipherInputStream> {

    private var mModel : CipherInputStream

    constructor(model : CipherInputStream){
        mModel = model
    }


    override fun loadData(priority: Priority, callback: DataFetcher.DataCallback<in CipherInputStream>) {
        var buffer = ByteArray(1024)

        callback.onDataReady(mModel)

    }


    override fun getDataClass(): Class<CipherInputStream> {
        return CipherInputStream::class.java
    }

    override fun cleanup() {
        mModel.close()
    }

    override fun getDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSource.LOCAL
    }

    override fun cancel() {
    }
}


//custom ModelLoaderFactory
class EncryptedModelLoaderFactory  : ModelLoaderFactory<CipherInputStream, CipherInputStream> {
    override fun build(p0: MultiModelLoaderFactory): ModelLoader<CipherInputStream, CipherInputStream> {
        return EncryptedModelLoader()
    }

    override fun teardown() {
    }
}

//GlideAppModule
@GlideModule
class MAGM : AppGlideModule(){


    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
        registry.prepend(CipherInputStream::class.java, CipherInputStream::class.java, EncryptedModelLoaderFactory())
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2019-06-15 11:14:26.690 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@df78e5a with size [14x14]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.690 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@df78e5a with size [270x270]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.692 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@5903626 with size [270x270]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.692 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@8b98eb2 with size [14x14]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.693 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@cade3fe with size [14x14]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.694 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@cade3fe with size [270x270]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.694 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@5903626 with size [14x14]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
2019-06-15 11:14:26.695 7547-7547/com.example.enead.secretcalculator_001 W/Glide: Load failed for javax.crypto.CipherInputStream@8b98eb2 with size [270x270]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{CipherInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{CipherInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).